# Boost Circular Buffer push_back inserts data at front

Tags: c++, boost

I have below code:

```
#include "boost/circular_buffer.hpp"

int main()
{
    // Create a circular buffer with a capacity for 3 integers.
    boost::circular_buffer<int> cb(3);

    // Insert threee elements into the buffer.
    cb.push_back(1);


    int a = cb[0];  // a == 1

}
```

As per documentation push_back API means *"Insert a new element at the end of the circular_buffer"* - then how cb[0] is 1? Shouldn't cb[2] should store value 1?

=======================================UPDATE=============================

```
// Insert threee elements into the buffer.
cb.push_front(11);
cb.push_back(2);
cb.push_back(3);

int a = cb[0];  // a == 11
int b = cb[1];  // b == 2
int c = cb[2];  // c == 3
```

It seems that in case there are 0 elements in an buffer it takes up the first but if the same has one then it puts it at the end

Comment: You're confusing yourself by overthinking this. The behaviour of `push_back` is consistent and does not depend on how many elements there are to begin with. It adds one to the logical end, period. I think you're just misunderstanding what "start" and "end" mean in this context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The buffer has *capacity* for three elements, but only contains one.

When you do your first `push_back`, you push to the end of a series of zero elements. So the new element becomes the first.

If you want to fill it up completely on construction, [you can do that!](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/circular_buffer.html#idp9066352-bb) Just like you would with a vector:

```
boost::circular_buffer<int> cb(3, 0);
```

But then, your first `push_back` will *still* alter `cb[0]`, because it's a circular buffer! That means it wraps around to the front when full. `cb[3]` is out of range. There is no `cb[3]`.

Comment: Thanks  - yes the last index will be 2 - cb[2] - however can you please exaplain "push to the end of a series of zero elements. So the new element becomes the first."?

Comment: Thanks I have updated the question as per my understanding and noted the behaviour as mentioned by you

Comment: @Programmer Sorry, I don't know how else to explain it. It's pretty simple. You start with no elements. Then you add an element. So now you have one element. That's the first element, out of a total of one element.

Answer (score 6):

No, because the element got inserted at the end of the buffer.

This is your empty buffer:

```
[ ] [ ] [ ]
```

After calling `push_back(1)` it looks like this:

```
[1] [ ] [ ]
```

After calling `push_back(2) it looks like this:

```
[1] [2] [ ]
```

Comment: Yes that seems the case - then why API is called push_back()?

Comment: Because it's pushing the element to the back, that's what I was trying to explain. 'back' doesn't refer to the last cell in the buffer but to the first free cell, meaning the last of all occupied cells

Comment: Yes as per output it matches what you state - but - https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/circular_buffer.html#idp8551216-bb states - "Insert a new element at the end of the circular_buffer. " - I agree to what you state based on the ouput but the documentation is probably confusing

Comment: @Programmer It's the same terminology used by standard containers like vector. So if you understand those (from your book) then you understand this. The underlying reserved memory is not the same as the "logical" collection of elements that you have added to the container.

Comment: @Programmer -- The documentation is not confusing if you don't read so much into it.  It does mean "the item is placed in the back", but that is conceptual.  Internally, multiple things are happening to keep the integrity of the circular queue.  The "front" needs to be adjusted, `begin()` is now changed, etc.  So the optimal way of doing a "push_back" is to merely overwrite the element that was "front" and adjust `begin()` and `front()`.